# How prove $A^2=0$,if $AB-BA=A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> let $A_{2\times 2}$ matrix, and  The matrix $B$ is  order  square,such
>   $$AB-BA=A$$ show that
>   $$A^2=0$$

My idea: since $$Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$$ so
$$Tr(A)=Tr(AB-BA)=Tr(AB)-Tr(BA)=0$$

Question:2

if $A_{n\times n}$ matrix,and the matrix $B$ is order square,such
$$AB-BA=A$$
then we also have
$$A^2=0?$$
and then I can't Continue .Thank you

Comment: What does "matrix $B$ is *order square*" mean?

Answer (score 25):

You say that $tr(A) = tr(AB)-tr(BA)=0$. Therefore Cayley Hamilton equation tells us that $A^2 = \det(A) I_2$.

On the other hand we have $A^2= A^2B-ABA=ABA-BA^2$. Therefore $2A^2 = A^2B-BA^2=0$ since $A^2$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: It's very very Nice!Thank you

Comment: so if $A_{n\times n},B_{n\times n}$ this reslut is also true?and you methods is also works?

Comment: @chinamath : We use the fact that we are in the $2 \times 2$ case because $A$ satisfies its characteristic polynomial which has the form $X^2 - \mathrm{tr}(A) X + \det(A)$. In the $n \times n$ case you would have to deal with the other exterior powers (which are the other coefficients of the characteristic polynomial), and this is not obvious that it would work.

Comment: Is there a counter example to the question in characteristic two?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva In characteristic two $A = \binom{0\,1}{1\,0}$, $B = \binom{0\,0}{0\,1}$ form a counterexample.

Comment: @martini,you example is not counterexample

Comment: @math110 Why? $AB = \binom{0\,1}{0\,0}$, $BA = \binom{0\,0}{1\,0}$, so $AB - BA = A$ but $A^2 = I_2 \ne 0$.

Comment: Great proof. But I would say that $A^2 = -\det(A) I_2$

Comment: @martini,your example $AB-BA=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ -1&0\end{bmatrix}\neq A ?$

Comment: @math110 In *characteristic two*, $-1 = 1$, so: yes. I do not aim to give a counterexample for other characteristic, as there the above proof thows no such examples exist.

Comment: A remark: I think that the general result (in characteristic $0$) in dimension $n$ is that $A$ is nilpotent. To see this, one prove by induction that $kA^k=A^k B-B A^k$, and let $M(x)=x^s+\cdots+a_k x^k+\cdots+a_0$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$. Then $\sum_{k=0}^s ka_k A^k=0$, and  $\sum ka_k x^k=sM(x)$, hence $a_k=0$ for $k<s$, $M(x)=x^s$, and as $s\leq n$, $A^n=0$.

Comment: @Kelenner: I think it is $2^kA^k=A^kB-BA^k$. To prove that $A$ is nilpotent it is enough to prove that $tr(A^k)=0$ for each $k$, which you did. After that you can deduce that all eigenvalues are zero using a Vandermonde system.

Comment: @Beni Bogosel: In fact, you have $2A^2=A^2B-BA^2$, so you get multipling by $A$ $2A^3=A^3B-ABA^2$ and $2A^3=A^2BA-BA^3$, summing you get $$4A^3=A^3B-BA^3+A(AB-BA)A=A^3B-BA^3+A^3$$ so $3A^3=A^3B-BA^3$.

Comment: @Kelenner: I'm sorry. I didn't make all the computations.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative geometric approach:

- We have $A\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ and it can be assumed that $B\in \mathfrak{sl}_2$ as well. Hence $A$, $B$ can be seen as vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}\in \mathbb{C}^3$. In this picture, $[A,B]\sim \vec{a}\wedge \vec{b}$ and $\operatorname{Tr}AB\sim \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}.$
- Now since $\vec{a}\wedge \vec{b}\sim \vec{a}$,
  taking the scalar product with $\vec{a}$, we get $\operatorname{Tr}A^2\sim\vec{a}\cdot \vec{a}=0 $. As for $A\in\mathfrak{sl}_2$ one has $A^2=\frac{\operatorname{Tr}A^2}{2} I$, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. $\operatorname{tr}{A}=0$
2. If $\det{A}=0$, then $A^2=0$ (By Cayley-Hamilton theorem)

Suppose $\det{A}\neq 0$ then $A$ is invertible. $$\begin{align}I&=A^{-1}A\\&=A^{-1}(AB-BA)\\&=B-A^{-1}BA\end{align}$$ Implies $\operatorname{tr}{I}=0$ (!)

Comment: Provided $\textrm{char}{F}\neq 0$ where $A\in M_n(F) $ ,otherwise $\textrm{tr}{I}=0$ .

Answer (score -1):

$AB - BA = A \Rightarrow A^2B - ABA = A^2 \Rightarrow$ $$-ABA = A^2(I-B)$$
$AB - BA = A \Rightarrow ABA - BA^2 = A^2 \Rightarrow$ $$ABA = (I+B)A^2$$
Adding this identities: $0 = A^2(I-B) + (I+B)A^2$

Comment: I believe this is flawed: $A^2B$ in the second identity is actually $BA^2$.

Comment: it looks fine to me: in the second identify $(AB-BA)A=ABA-BA^2$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user103828 $ABA-BA^2=A^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $ABA=A^2+BA^2=(I+B)A^2$.

Comment: You are absolutelly right, in the second identity it should be $ABA = (I+B)A^2$. Adding we would get $0 = A^2(I-B) + (I+B)A^2$ and I don't know how this information would be useful. Sorry =(